# use custom class in another class (same package)

Tags: java, class

I just started Java and search everywhere, but for whatever reason wasn't able to find a solution. My problem seems simple to me: I have two classes in the same folder, that folder is my package, so to illustrate:

```
packageE/Class1.java
packageE/Class2.java
```

I need to make an instance of class 1 in class2, but it just doesn't work. Here's a sample:

**file path:** `packageE/Class1.java`

```
package packageE
public class Class1 {... something ...}
```

**file path:** `packageE/Class2.java`

```
package packageE
public class Class2 {
    public void main (String[] args) {
        Class1 object = new Class1();
    }
```

I get this error

```
Class2.java:52: error: cannot find symbol

                    Class1 object = new Class1();
                    ^
  symbol:   class Class1

  location: class Class2

Class2.java:52: error: cannot find symbol

                    Class1 object = new Class1();
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Class1

  location: class Class2
```

As requested, the full source code:
NOTE: class1 = ClientIndividual AND class2 = Stakeholders

**FIRST FILE**

```
package substitutiva;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stakeholders {
    static ArrayList<Object> companyList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> individualList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addToRegistry (Object person) {
        System.out.println(person.getClass());
        companyList.add(person);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // select action
        String selectedAction = "";
        while (selectedAction != "1" && selectedAction != "2") {
            System.out.println("Selecione uma ação:");
            System.out.print("1. Cadastrar");
            System.out.println("2. Listar registros");
            selectedAction = read.nextLine();
            
            if (selectedAction != "1" && selectedAction != "2") {
                System.out.println("Opção indisponível! \n");
            }
        }

        // select person
        String selectedOption = "";
        while (selectedOption != "1" && selectedOption != "2" && selectedOption != "3") {
            System.out.println("Qual tipo de pessoa deseja acessar?");
            System.out.println("1. Funcionário");
            System.out.println("2. Cliente PF");
            System.out.println("3. Cliente PJ");
            selectedOption = read.nextLine();
            
            if (selectedOption != "1" && selectedOption != "2" && selectedOption != "3") {
                System.out.println("Opção indisponível! \n");
            }
        }

        // register
        if (selectedAction == "1") {
            switch (selectedOption) {
                case "1":
                    
                    break;
                case "2":
                    ClientIndividual personObject = new ClientIndividual();
                    addToRegistry(personObject);
                    break;
                case "3":
                
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // list
        else if (selectedAction == "2") {
            switch (selectedOption) {
                case "1":
                    break;
                case "2":
                    break;
                case "3":
                    break;
                
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        

        read.close();
    }

}
```

**SECOND FILE**

```
package substitutiva;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientIndividual implements Person {
    String name;
    String cpf;

    @Override
    public void registerPerson() {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Nome: ");
        this.name = read.nextLine();

        System.out.println("CPF: ");
        this.cpf = read.nextLine();

        read.close();
    }

    // constructor
    public ClientIndividual(){};

    // getters & setters
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

}
```

**THIRD FILE (INTERFACE)**

```
package substitutiva;

public interface Person {
    public void registerPerson ();
}
```

**THE ORIGINAL ERROR**

```
Stakeholders.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
                    ClientIndividual personObject = new ClientIndividual();
                    ^
  symbol:   class ClientIndividual
  location: class Stakeholders
Stakeholders.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
                    ClientIndividual personObject = new ClientIndividual();
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class ClientIndividual
  location: class Stakeholders
```

Comment: Have you imported that class in the other two classes?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran classes in the same package don't need to be imported.

Comment: `public class Class1 () {... something ...}` - My Java is a bit rusty, but I do not think this is a valid class definition. Remove the `()`.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Since it is in the same package I don't think I need to import it, but I tried it anyway and doesn't work

Comment: @Fildor that was my mistake writing the question, not in the original code, updating now

Comment: @Fildor if that was the issue wouldnt the IDE throw an error instead? ```java: '{' expected```

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I can only judge what OP tells us, but probably, yes. It would be a different error. Was a copy/paste issue in the question, apparently.

Comment: try clicking invalidate cache and then click invalidate and restart??

Comment: @DepletedKnowledge What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Fildor I'm using vscode

Comment: Please give us the EXACT source code you are using. Note that your code here ... lacks the trailing ";" after the package statement.

Comment: @Abra No, the above code does not compile fine. Maybe you added a ";" after the import statement just so ... thats the thing. Details matter.

Comment: What is `Stakeholders.java:52`? Another typo and not part of the original problem?

Comment: VSCode - Interesting choice. Any Plugins for Java Development?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS the problem was in like 52 and Stakeholders = Class2

Comment: Stop. First read [mcve]. Then understand: you should FIRST try to break things down. Try to find the SMALLEST amount of code that gives the error. Then post THAT.

Comment: ^^ I think most of us suspect an issue with how you (respective vscode) are compiling this. Can you bring a single-file program to run? Just a dumb "Hello World"?

Comment: @Abra I'm using vscode, compiling in terminal $java Stakeholders.java

Comment: @Fildor I have the Java plugins for vscode

Comment: `java` is not used for compiling, `javac` is. It's possible you're accidentally invoking Java's [single-file mode](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330). Try using `javac` instead.

Comment: @GhostCat, I posted the smallest amount of code, but was requested the full source code, should've read the comments beforehand.

Comment: @Fildor I can compile and run normally.

Comment: Its okay, it isnt that much. Side note: `static ArrayList<Object>` is not a useful thing to do. In Java all "objects" are of type Object, you want to be more specific, for example: `static ArrayList<Person>` for a list that is supposed to hold Person objects.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, tried using javac and got the same errors

Comment: @DepletedKnowledge do you have same error with any other java code you run or this one in particular? Are you still able to run any of ur previous java code now

Comment: @GhostCat, vscode was bothering me with linters without static, I just wanted to see what would say with it. PS: code not finished yet, still in early stages. I appreciate the tip ;)

Comment: @experimentunit1998X, how would I do that?

Comment: by running any other Java code/files you have? I wanted to know if the issue is with the current code you are writing or the issue pops up for all the other java files you have.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X, other files run normally.

Comment: _I'm using vscode, compiling in terminal $java Stakeholders.java_ Since `StakeHolders` references `ClentIndividual`, you need to compile `ClientIndividual` **before** you compile `StakeHolders` and before you compile `ClientIndividual` you need to compile `Person`. Refer to the documentation for [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html)

Comment: _I just started Java and search everywhere_ I recommend Oracle's [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: It was a compiling error, thank you all for the help! 

Comment: @SilvioMayolo In recent Java version (I believe since Java 10), you can run single file applications by using `java YourApplication.java`, it will automatically compile and then run that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are compiling manually via `javac`

Change the working folder to the root folder where your files are, not `substitutiva` and use `javac substitutiva/Stakeholders.java` command for compile